# Use C# to create EventSystemTopics and Subscriptions just like Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventgrid

Azure Service Bus has libraries in C# which allows us to create Queues at run time.

I'm looking for something similar for event grid where I can create AzureEventSystemTopics through code and configure

Any references or code sample would be helpfull

Comment: Currently, the best that you can do is the legacy management package, Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid. 

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for something similar for event grid where I can create AzureEventSystemTopics through code and configure

*Please check the below steps if it helps to fix the issue*:

As per this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/system-topics#system-topics-as-azure-resources), you can use ARM, REST APIs or CLI to create a system topic and then subscription on that created topic.

If you want to create this system topic programmatically (eg: C#), you can make a call to the REST APIs using C# Code.

This System topic can be created in 2 different ways which are automatic and manual.

- Automatically, in the sense - When you create the Event Grid Subscription on Azure Resource like the Azure Functions, then system topic is created automatically with the suffix of GUID to given resource name.
- Manually means you can name the system topic before creating an event grid subscription for that specific system topic.

The point to note when cleaning up the resources in above two cases is system topic can be deleted in the way we created i.e., manually for manual creation and automatically deleted for automatically created system topics.